# Java has Spring Security what PHP and Ruby on Rails has to do the same?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, spring

What is used in PHP and Ror to do the same as is done in [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)?

Does it have all or most of the same features as Spring Security? Which one is easier to setup?

Comment: Spring Security is a component for Spring, which is a framework for the Java language. PHP is a language, not a framework, hence not comparable.

Comment: there are PHP and Ruby frameworks that do have security related classes however...Rails for Ruby...Zend, Code Igniter, or Kohana for PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP try PEAR libs: http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=1&catname=Authentication
For Ror maybe try Clearence: https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance